# Specify the account in domain format Error in SQL Server 2016 installation on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2016, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2016 on Windows 10 Pro. In the Server Configuration tab I need to provide the account names, the services will be running as. Independent whether I provide virtual or local accounts an error is generated and I cannot proceed:

[image: Specify the accountin domain format]

Comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message you are getting because you did not provide any service account for the following services. You can see those are blank in the picture you provided.

1. SQL Server PolyBase Engine.
2. SQL Server PolyBase Data Movement.